# How to prevent labels from one layer from overlapping features in another layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, cartography, labeling

I am working ArcMap10.1 software. When I was labeling on point feature automatically label fall on line. Label must not fall on line.  I'm not aware how to solve this issues. I have attached an example image to show the problem.

[image]

Comment: You need the labeling toolbar in arcmap. Find the button called 'Label weight ranking' and change your line feature weight to high and label weight to low which will try to avoid lines but may skip labels. If you can use maplex label engine (ArcMap options, Data view tab, default label engine change from standard to maplex). This will give MUCH better labels and more control on where to put them and what to avoid. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s800000050000000

Comment: What is the Button section in Conflict Detection that opens when we click Placement Properties in the Labels section of properties?

Answer (score 8):

You can try using the Maplex labeling engine which will give you more control than the standard labeling engine.  In the labeling toolbar, enable Maplex.

[image]

There are several options in which you can adjust the settings for feature weights and overlapping labels.  See the **[ESRI documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Preventing_labels_from_overlapping_certain_features/00s80000003t000000/)**.

> Weights can range from 0 to 1,000. Features with high weights are less
>   likely to have labels placed over them.

[image]

The Maplex settings are numerous.  You can read more about them in the **[help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/What_is_the_Maplex_Label_Engine/00s80000007m000000/)**.

Answer (score 6):

This is possible by assigning a higher [weight](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s80000001p000000.htm) to the line layer's features than to the point layer's labels.

Open the Properties dialog for the line layer, and choose the Labels > Placement option, then set a High value for the Feature Weight.

[image]

This causes ArcMap to move those labels which would have overlapped the lines, or to omit drawing them where necessary.

[image]

If you want manual control over the labels, and/or you want to force the placement of labels which don't display automatically using this method, you can [convert the labels to annotation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s80000001r000000.htm) and move them precisely.

Comment: Hi @Stephen manual work it will take huge time thatswhat i have posted automatic options. Anyway thanks to respones.

Comment: @RajGovind note that only the last paragraph of this answer is manual - the labelling options are fully automatic

Comment: Standard labelling engine will give you a result, maplex will give a much better result but for a perfect result it is necessary to convert to annotation (either map or feature) and push them around. It just depends on whether it's a scratch map (labelled), quick map (labelled well) or published map (labelled to cartographic principles).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use "Standard Engine" then
There is an option "Label Offset" in standard engine. Combination of "Feature Weight" and "Label Offset" may produce a good placing..[image: Tutorial_Image]